# How to make if else menu with active class in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, frameworks

I want to ask how to make if else function menu with active class. here is my code in controller.

```
public function index(){

    //i try with this but error 
    $data['activeTab'] == "home";

    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('header');

    $this->load->view('content',$data);

    $this->load->view('footer');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}

public function about(){

    //i try with this but error
    $data['activeTab'] == "about";

    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('header');

    $this->load->view('content-about',$data);

    $this->load->view('footer');
    $this->load->view('foot');
}
```

and here is my view

```
<body>  
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!--HEADER START-->
            <div class="page-header">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>codeig/index.php/site">HEADER</a>
            </div>
        <!--HEADER END-->

        <!--NAVBAR START-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <!--i try with this but error-->
                        <li class="<?php echo ($activeTab=="home")?"active":""; ?>"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>codeig/index.php/site">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>codeig/index.php/site/about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        <!--NAVBAR END-->
```

I'll try with `activetabs`. But there is an error.

Comment: Are you defining `$activeTab` anywhere?

Comment: @Bankzilla i already defining anywhere, stillsame

Comment: `but error.` can you please explain what error you get??

Comment: @Saty error Undefined variable: data and Undefined variable: activeTab

Comment: What is your view name and paste you full error with line number

Comment: @Saty Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/Site.php

Line Number: 29

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\controllers\Site.php
Line: 29
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: @Saty and this

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: activeTab

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\views\header.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\controllers\Site.php
Line: 27
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Set `$data` in header view `$this->load->view('header',$data);` in your controller

Comment: @Saty stillsame, still error, same error

Comment: @mawlynx Check my asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to

```
$data['activeTab'] == "home";
$data['activeTab'] == "about";
```

this

```
$data['activeTab'] = "home";
$data['activeTab'] = "about";
```

If you use `==`, You get this Error

> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined variable: activeTab
>   Filename: xx/yyy.php
>   Line Number: xxx

Comment: `==` is used for compare not use for assign value.

Comment: so then why you update your answer?? LOL :D http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31284141/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$data` array to your `viwes` ANd `==` is your for compair use `=` for assign value

**Controller**

```
public function index(){

    //i try with this but error 
    $data['activeTab'] = "home";

    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('header',$data);

    $this->load->view('content',$data);

    $this->load->view('footer',$data);
    $this->load->view('foot',$data);
}

public function about(){

    //i try with this but error
    $data['activeTab'] = "about";

    $this->load->view('head',$data);
     $this->load->view('header',$data);

    $this->load->view('content-about',$data);

    $this->load->view('footer',$data);
    $this->load->view('foot',$data);
}
```

Comment: okk `print_r($activeTab);` in your viwe and check what it return

Comment: this the error

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: activeTab

Filename: views/content-about.php

Line Number: 5

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\views\content-about.php
Line: 5
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\application\controllers\Site.php
Line: 43
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeig\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once